# iCloud Backup for CoreData - On Demand?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

If my objective is to create a cloud backup that a user can restore if they accidentally delete my app or a bug causes data loss (no need to share data across devices), what's the simplest option to backup user CoreData daily? 
(Note: The occasional full iPhone backup isn't sufficient)

When I read about CloudKit I see things like:

> You might wonder why you should choose CloudKit over Core Data, other commercial BaaS (Back end as a Service) offerings, or even rolling your own server...

But that's a problem because I would like to continue using CoreData! I do not want the user to depend on the cloud for data. I don't want syncing problems, online/offline issues, etc.

I would also like to avoid having the user login or create an account. According to Ray Wenderlich:

> Since CloudKit uses the iCloud credentials entered when the device is set up (or entered after set up via the Settings app), there’s no need to build complicated login screens.

I see some apps use Facebook login but I'd even like to avoid that! So can I use CloudKit to avoid login screens but also still use CoreData?

Although code answers are great, just a general answer on what API/design-pattern is used for this type of functionality would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use CloudKit at the same time as CoreData to do this and it does avoid the login and cost overheads of many other cloud alternatives.

However as the two data models are not related, if your data is complex there will be a significant amount of code necessary to covert between them whenever the user selects to backup or restore.

Are you sure relying on the normal iOS backup functionality is not sufficient?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply and thanks for answering. My users seem to want a backup option. My data is simple, strings, ints, and dates. No relational database setup. Is that simple enough to do this in a clean way or will I still find it eventually gets messy?

Comment: Yes, I think that could be reasonably accommodated with CloudKit without excessive effort. I think your instinct to keep it simple is right as full multi device data synchronisation has a lot of edge cases to catch - but make sure your app has appropriate checks and your users are aware of the limitation - e.g. What happens if they do access the backup from another device?